# При обращении к серверу выдает не удалось создать защищенный канал ssl/tls WS2012

Tags: c#, .net

Я пытаюсь с сервера получить данные изображения следующим кодом

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
}
```

Но у меня выводит ошибку

> не удалось создать защищенный канал ssl/tls

Проблема не решается через ServiceProtocol, указанием tls1.2 | tls1.3.
Также игнорирование сертификата тоже не помогает.
Я выяснил, что ws2012 R2 может не поддержвать определенные типы шифрования, которые поддерживает сервер, но при этом браузеры без проблем работают с этим ресурсом.
Если браузер поставляется с своим пулом типов шифрования, то я подумал, что может быть есть способ или настройка в стандартной .net библиотеке, как добавить chiper suits при обращении к серверу, но нашел только, как это сделать с помощью curl, но тянуть зависимость ради этого не хочется, вот это решение

```
static byte[] GetToken(string url)
{
    //This string is for extracting libcurl and ssl libs to the bin directory.
    CurlResources.Init();
    var global = CurlNative.Init();
    var easy = CurlNative.Easy.Init();
    byte[] content;

    try
    {
        var dataCopier = new DataCallbackCopier();
        
        CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.URL, url);
        CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.WRITEFUNCTION, dataCopier.DataHandler);
        //This string is needed when you call a https endpoint.
        //CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.CAINFO, CurlResources.CaBundlePath);

        //var headers = CurlNative.Slist.Append(SafeSlistHandle.Null, "Authorization: Bearer blablabla");
        //CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.HTTPHEADER, headers.DangerousGetHandle());
        //Your set of ciphers, full list is here https://curl.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html
        CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256");

        CurlNative.Easy.Perform(easy);

        using (var read = dataCopier.Stream)
        {
            content = read.ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        easy.Dispose();

        if (global == CURLcode.OK)
            CurlNative.Cleanup();
    }

    return content;
}
```

Поэтому может кто то сталкивался, как это можно обойти.
Временным решением стало развернуть отдельный сервис и роутить запросы к серваку через него, но я тоже не хочу к нему привязывать, ибо этот код (метод imageToByte) работал 3 года с ресурсом без перебоев, до сегодня

Comment: Вопрос остался незамеченным из-за недостатка меток.

Answer (score 1):

Решил добавив дополнительные алгоритмы шифрования в настройках(пришлось с сервера на 2012 на 2019 обновляться правда)